# Detecting specific images through mobile device camera

Tags: javascript, html, css, augmented-reality

I want to build a Web App that allows mobile users to point their device camera at content in a printed magazine to see additional information on their phones. I have a set of 15 images that I want to 'augment' with additional information. This information does not need to appear in 3D space. I only need to be able to detect when a user looks at one of those images.

I have seen tons of different recognition techniques (feature detection, face recognition, …), but haven't been able to find one specific to my use case.

Is there a Javascript Library out there to provide the functionality? Or do I need to train a ML Model myself with my set of reference images?

Answer (score 0):

A webapp can be [taught](https://a.kabachnik.info/reading-barcodes-with-built-in-camera-with-html5.html) to detect barcodes.  If you can embed compatible barcodes into the 15 magazine images, this will just work.